# Vue Component Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component

I have a counter component - pretty straight forward.

```
<div> + </div>
    <input type="text" v-model="countData" />
<div> - </div>
```

Detailed code is here - https://github.com/Shreerang/Vue-Nuggets/blob/master/src/components/QuantitySelector/QuantitySelector.vue

I am trying to unit test this component.

```
it('Renders a default quantity selector with the max count set to 6', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(QuantitySelector);
    wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').setValue('1');
    expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').element.value).toBe('1'); // notice here that the value is a String, whereas I expect it to be a Number

    wrapper.findAll('div').at(2).trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.countData).toBe('2'); // This fails as countData becomes "11" instead of doing a 1 + 1 = 2 and then becoming Number 2.

    expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').element.value).toBe(2); // You can notice the same thing as above.

    wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').setValue(wrapper.vm.countData); // Do I have to do this? This does not seem right to me :frowning:
});
```

I am not able to get this unit test to work! Any help with this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text fields contain text values. Note that you even specified a text value: `setValue('1')`. If you change the value in the input manually, (say, to 3) and press the increment button, it becomes 31. Your test is telling you the truth.

You need to change your functions to convert to number. [Update] As your comment informed me, Vue has a [`.number`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) modifier for `v-model` for this very purpose

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    name: 'quantity-selector',
    props: {
        count: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1,
        }, // Makes sense to have default product count value
        maxCount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 6,
        }, // maxCount makes sense when you have a restriction on the max quantity for a product
        iconDimensions: {
            type: Number,
            default: 15,
        },
        minusIconFillColor: {
            type: String,
            default: '#000',
        },
        plusIconFillColor: {
            type: String,
            default: '#000',
        },
        isCountEditable: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            countData: this.count,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        minusIconColor: function() {
            return this.countData === this.count ? '#CCC' : this.minusIconFillColor;
        },
        plusIconColor: function() {
            return this.countData === this.maxCount ? '#CCC' : this.plusIconFillColor;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        decrement: function() {
            if (this.countData > this.count) {
                this.countData -= 1;
            }
        },
        increment: function() {
            if (this.countData < this.maxCount) {
                this.countData += 1;
            }
        },
        adjustCount: function() {
            if (this.countData > this.maxCount) {
                this.countData = this.maxCount;
            } else if (this.countData < this.count) {
                this.countData = this.count;
            } else {
                if (isNaN(Number(this.countData))) {
                    this.countData = this.count;
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

```css
.nugget-quantity-counter {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter div:first-child {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter div:nth-child(2) {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter input[type='text'] {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter div:last-child {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter > div {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nugget-quantity-counter > div > svg {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="decrement">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" :width="iconDimensions" :height="iconDimensions">
                <g>
                    <path d='M64 0 M2 11 L2 13 L22 13 L22 11 Z' :fill="minusIconColor" />
                </g>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <input v-if="isCountEditable" type="text" v-model.number="countData" @blur="adjustCount" />
  <div v-else>{{countData}}</div>
  <div @click="increment">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" :width="iconDimensions" :height="iconDimensions">
                <g>
                    <path d="M 11 2 L 11 11 L 2 11 L 2 13 L 11 13 L 11 22 L 13 22 L 13 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 13 11 L 13 2 Z" :fill="plusIconColor" />
                </g>
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. I had figured out as much. The Number and Text String thing. What confuses me is that how is the component working as expected then. See here - https://ecommerce-vue-nuggets.herokuapp.com

Comment: It works as I describe: manually set the value of the first input to 3, then click the plus. You have 31 in the blank. You start with a number value, but when the value is changed in the text item, it becomes a text value.

Comment: Hi Roy. Though your answer pointed me in the right direction, I think we do not need to add Number(this.countData) everywhere. Instead we can `<input type="text" v-model.number="countData" />` This `.number` modifier on `v-model` will fix the issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer with that, which is of course a better option. Thanks for sharing that information!

Comment: I too was given this answer on the Vue Forum! Thanks to LinusBorg - https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-unit-test/48709/2

Comment: I only have 1 question left on this and then I can mark your answer as the correct answer! `wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').element.value` will still be of type `String`

When I do,

`expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').element.value).toBe(1)`

It will still throw an error!

To fix this, I will have to do the following.

`expect(parseInt(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').element.value)).toBe(1)`

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: I prefer `Number(str)` to `parseInt(str)`, but yes, that's what you do.